# mysql take long time to get sum()

Tags: mysql, database

I have a table as in below schema which have got approximately 100,000 records.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `order_items` (
    `order_item_id` int(1) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `item_id` int(1) unsigned DEFAULT '0',
    `final_amt` double NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    PRIMARY KEY (`order_item_id`),
    KEY `item_id` (`item_id`),
    KEY `final_amt` (`final_amt`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci ;
```

(Please note that there some other fields and indexes also.)

When I run the below query, it takes about 10 - 20 seconds.

```
SELECT  item_id, SUM( final_amt) AS tot_final_amt
FROM  `order_items` 
GROUP BY item_id;
```

(There are about 350 distinct item_id values.)

How to make my result faster?

Comment: @1000111, 
KEY item_id (item_id), is that not an index for item_id column?

Comment: Sorry, I missed that. Please share the `Explain` result of your query.

Answer (score 0):

You do not use filtering criteria (WHERE) so it has to scan whole table. If you cannot use WHERE, you need to create a new table with purpose to store SUM() for every `item_id`. Every time `order_items` is changed, you need to update this new table as well (using TRIGGER for example as suggested by rkosegi). It is redundant but i think this is needed to speed up your query.

Comment: You may want to mention `TRIGGER`s which can help with this solution